# how to set vertical scroll bar for relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set vertical scroll bar for my relative

here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:text="Add Leg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="Quantity" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:text="25"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Calculate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Time to expiry" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="Volatality" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText02"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText01" 
        android:text="25"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText02"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="Risk free rate" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText03"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText02" 
        android:text="0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText03"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView03"
        android:text="Strike price" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText04"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="9200"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText03" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="Stock price" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText05"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView05"
        android:text="9009"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText04" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText05"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText05" 
        android:entries="@array/type_arrays"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView05"
        android:text="Type" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView07"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:text="Option type" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1" 
        android:entries="@array/option_arrays"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView08"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView07"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:text="Num of legs" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Spinner01"
         android:entries="@array/legs_arrays" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Clear All" />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the out put image [image]

I tried to set vertical scroll bar with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:text="Add Leg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="Quantity" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:text="25"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Calculate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Time to expiry" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="Volatality" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText02"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText01" 
        android:text="25"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText02"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="Risk free rate" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText03"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText02" 
        android:text="0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText03"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView03"
        android:text="Strike price" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText04"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="9200"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText03" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="Stock price" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText05"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView05"
        android:text="9009"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText04" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText05"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText05" 
        android:entries="@array/type_arrays"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView05"
        android:text="Type" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView07"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:text="Option type" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1" 
        android:entries="@array/option_arrays"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView08"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView07"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:text="Num of legs" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Spinner01"
         android:entries="@array/legs_arrays" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Clear All" />        
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

But it is giving output is as shown in image all the views are aligning on the top of the layout one upon other [image]

Please suggest me to set vertical scroll  bar for relative layout in my case.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollView` can only hold a single child. And that child must be `LinearLayout`. I think you can achieve your goal by putting an extra `LinearLayout` above the `RelativeLayout` like this.

You can also add this `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"` in your `ScrollView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset">
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:text="Add Leg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="Quantity" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:text="25"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Calculate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Time to expiry" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="Volatality" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText02"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText01" 
        android:text="25"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText02"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="Risk free rate" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText03"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText02" 
        android:text="0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText03"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView03"
        android:text="Strike price" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText04"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="9200"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText03" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="Stock price" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText05"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView05"
        android:text="9009"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText04" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText05"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText05" 
        android:entries="@array/type_arrays"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView05"
        android:text="Type" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView07"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:text="Option type" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1" 
        android:entries="@array/option_arrays"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView08"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView07"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:text="Num of legs" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Spinner01"
         android:entries="@array/legs_arrays" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Clear All" />        
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Technically ScrollView can hold a RelativeLayout. The Google webpage says so indirectly @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in ScrollView tag

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Edit Scroll height and width `fill_parent` or `"match_parent"`

And remove the line from RelativeLayout tag

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

hope it will work..